# Excel deduct every first number from every second

Tags: excel

I have a column of numbers in Excel, for example:

```
10
20
15
25
20
30
```

I need to deduct first line from second (20-10) third from forth (25-15) and so on. I have found some examples using `MOD`, but i couldn't apply it in a right way, unfortunately.

Comment: Hello. Sorry for not replying anything. I was in a trip and could not unfortunately even try this. I will do this today or latest tomorrow and will write a feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested a lot, but it should work!

It loops through the first column, starting from cell A1 down to A2, A3 etc, and sums up every couple of rows. The result is stored on the right (5 columns to the right, you see)

```
Sub Test()
' Select cell A1, *first line of data*.
Range("A1").Select

right_offset = 5

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

    Set r1 = Selection
    Set r2 = ActiveCell.offset(1, 0)

    ActiveCell.offset(1, right_offset).Select

    ActiveCell.Value = r2.Value - r1.Value

    ActiveCell.offset(-1, -right_offset).Select

    ' Step down 2 row from present location.
    ActiveCell.offset(2, 0).Select

Loop
End Sub
```

---

Edit: in order to run it, you can just open the VBA Editor (Alt+F11), copy-paste the code there, and press F5 to see if it works for your case!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Will try it later today and write a feedback. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it works! In this case could you please accept my answer?

Comment: Sure. I am pretty new here, so did not know i hat to accept. Thank you. I will try other proposals and write a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column with numbers is A, try this on cell B2:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,A2-A1,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in `D3:D80`.

```
Range("E4").Formula = "=D4-D3"
Range("E3:E4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E3:E80")
```